# AJAX call and clean JSON but Syntax Error: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am making a cross domain JSONP call using this code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: 'http://mnews.hostoi.com/test.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        method: "GET",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.Error || data.Response) {
                exists = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

When debugging in Firebug, I get the following error:

[image]

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

However, when I pass my json object (available through the link in the JQ code) through a tool like jsonlint.com, it says it is valid JSON. And I don't find any anomalies either. How could it be returning a syntax error? Is it some JSONP detail I am not getting or what?

### JSON Sample

```
{"news":[ {
  "sentences": [
    "Neuroscientists have discovered abnormal neural activity...", 
    "The researchers found that these mice showed many symptoms...", 
    "\"Therefore,\" the study authors say, \"our findings provide a novel.."
  ], 
  "summaryId": "ZJEmY5", 
  "title": "Abnormal neural activity linked to schizophrenia"
}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May we see a sample of the `json` string? Just in case =)

Comment: Sure, it's here: http://mnews.hostoi.com/test.json

Comment: Looks like you're returning JSON rather than JSONP. JSON != JSONP

Comment: @KevinB has the correct answer

Comment: Just 1 more question, how should I change the JSON to JSONP? Should I add something in the beginning? The info on the web is kind of confusing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but I'm not using JSONP (same server), the ajax call is in json datatype and the json object is a valid multidimensional array coming from php. The array has 2 array inside with a string as a key. The problem is the string. If I use the normal int numeration for array keys all works fine. There is a way to fix this? It's much more readable with the string and not the decimal. thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JSONP is not JSON. A JSONP response would consist of a JavaScript script containing only a function call (to a pre-defined function) with one argument (which is a JavaScript object literal conforming to JSON syntax).

The response you are getting is JSON, not JSONP so your efforts to handle it as JSONP fail.

Change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'` (or remove the line entirely, the server issues the correct content-type so you don't need to override it).

Since your script is running on a different origin to the JSON then you will also need to [take steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) (most, but not all, of which require that you control the host serving the JSON) to work around the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: My script is running on a different origin, yes. I will try to implement CORS, using the link your provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The error is because it is returning JSON not JSONP.

JSONP is supposed to look like

```
someCallBackString({ The Object });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working example

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'http://xxx.amazonaws.com/file.json',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 jsonpCallback: 'callback',
 success: function(json){
   console.log(json);
 }
});
```

And you should put `callback` in the beginning of your `file.json` like :

`callback({"item":{".......`

Answer (score 2):

As epascarello [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456225/386579), the JSONP response must be sent like:

```
callBackFunction({ JSON Object })
```

And the caller function can then be setup like:

```
var url =  "http://someremoteurl.com/json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
    callBackFunction(data);
});
```

Then you can loop over the response data as:

```
function callBackFunction(data)
{
   console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "**callback=?**" parameter, your response on the server side should look like this:

```
$_callback = $_GET['callback'];    
echo $_callback . '(' . json_encode(YOUR_VARIABLE) . ');';
```

If "**callback=?**" parameter is not defined, your response should look like this:

```
echo '[' . json_encode($_return_array) . ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is related to Ruby then in your controller make sure that you render the format correctly. example:

```
def view_product
   data = Product.find params[:id]
   render :json =>  data, :callback => params[:callback]
end
```

In your render method, you should have the **:callback** parameter otherwise it will render in json instead of jsonp.

Comment: The question wasn't about Ruby at all.