# jQuery: getJSON request not working

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am trying to access data using getJSON function of jquery but not able to succeed.

This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    $.getJSON( "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/eur_usd/", function( data ) {
    alert(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me in getting this work?

Will really appreciate.

Comment: I assume that is an external domain to the one making the request in which case this will not work due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You need to check if the API you're querying accepts JSONP requests, or is setup for CORS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON works locally, but not cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849802/jquery-getjson-works-locally-but-not-cross-domain)

Comment: Try using console.log(data.responseData); to view any errors

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement

Answer (score 10):

try to have error message in ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {

            $.getJSON("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/eur_usd/", function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
                .error(function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                })
            );
        });
    });
```

Note: Xhr.responseText will provide you the stack trace of error, it returns in the html format

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `JSON.stringify(data)` instead of just data