# JSONP + SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I've been googling this, found recommendations but I couldn't apply correctly.
I am calling a json API from other domain so i used jsonp.  Please check my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        GetParam(function (data) {
            alert(data.toString());
        });
    });
 });

  function GetParam(func) {
      $.getJSON("http://test.com/api/getparams.ashx?callback=?", function (result) {});
  }
```

It is able to call the API and show the result. It's just that there is this semicolon issue.

[image]

From what i have researched, they say i should return a jsonp format but how can i do that? Note: I don't have access to the source code of the API.

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot make the API return JSONP, you cannot use JSONP. It's as simple as that. JSONP is not a silver bullet for cross-domain connections, it actually has to be supported by the server.

Comment: the server endpoint does not seem to be returning jsonp data. If this feature is not available, you might consider using `CORS` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX call and clean JSON but Syntax Error: missing ; before statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement)

Comment: Do you control the domain that is sending the data?

Comment: Are you sure the API supports JSONP in the first place?  Adding `callback=?` doesn't magically make it work, the API needs to support it first.  Check its docs.

Comment: thanks. it is now clear to me that the API should support jsonp first. To fix this easier and faster, I have asked the owner of the API to add crossdomain.xml and allow request from my domain :) then I am now using the normal json.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jsonp use `$.ajax({dataType: 'jsonp'...});`