# Cross Domain jQuery Ajax call - Syntax missing error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I couldn't access the webservice call from cross domain. Please advice. I have pasted my source here.

PHP: webservice response

```
$data['response'] = 2;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: cross-domain-url,
data:{ param1:'123', param2:'123' },
dataType:'jsonp',
crossDomain: 'true',
async: true,
success:function (data) {
    alert('success');
},
error:function(){
    alert('error');
}
});
```

Cross Domain URL response:

```
{"ResultCode":2}
```

Always I am getting Error only. I don't know why. I can see the following message in Firefox inspect area.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"ResultCode":2}
```

Please help me.

Solution:

Modify the line like,
    echo 'someCallBackString('.json_encode($data).');';
instead of echo json_encode($data);

Created the function someCallBackString and proceeded my implementations.

Comment: There must be a filename and line number being printed along with the error. That might help you debug. Can you check?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement

You have to build the JSON rightly

Comment: @Pulkit: Thanks. I have checked the file. That contains "{"ResultCode":2}" only. It shows an error on 13th character. That is ":".

Comment: if you want to encode data why you are using header() because it will response you on ajax success and secondly you have miss ';' operator in your script please provide the line number and first direct hit your cross domain url

Comment: What is the output of your cross domain url? i mean is it producing valid json?

Comment: @owsata: Thanks for your response. But, we can't receive data from cross domain using JSON. So only I used JSONP.

Comment: @Jai: I have received {"ResultCode":2} from the cross domain.

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed: I think you misunderstood my question. Please check the comments..

Comment: @user2987836 how did you checked? by hitting the url in the web browser right.

Comment: @Jai: Yes. I checked it via browser.

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed: We can't change JSONP to JSON. Similarly, if we use like someCallBackString({ The Object });, the response will be error only. No success.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling jQuery to make a JSON-P request (`dataType:'jsonp'`), but your server is returning JSON.

Consequently the browser is trying to execute a JSON text as if it was a JavaScript program (and it can't because it isn't).

Either:

1. Remove the `dataType` property from the object so that jQuery will use the HTTP Content-Type to determine that it is JSON *and* add [access control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to permit your site to access the data on the other domain *or*
2. Return JSON-P instead of JSON

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. 1. It is a cross domain related issue. I couldn't receive response without datatype. 2. We can't return JSON-P in webservice response.

Comment: 1. You need to implement the *entire* solution, not just the first half of it. The server must output HTTP headers that grant permission for JS in a browser to read it from another site. 2. Then you must use solution 1.

Comment: How to give Access Control Headers. Please advice.

Comment: I have added the following codes in webservice. But still getting the same. header('Content-type: application/json'); header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); echo json_encode($data);

Comment: That should work. Look at your browser's developer tools. Does the JavaScript console report any errors? Does the Net tab show the HTTP request being sent and the response coming back? Are they correct? Is the status code OK?

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I got the response in Net tab without adding the access control headers. My issue is getting error in ajax call. Although I got the response in Net tab, but the error alert box is displayed instead of success.

Comment: OK, so you got the response. Is the response correct? Is the status code OK? Does the JavaScript error console report any errors?

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. I have added the following line in webservice. echo 'someCallBackString('.json_encode($data).');'; And Created the function someCallBackString, proceeded the upcoming steps.

Comment: @user2987836 — That was option 2 in my answer, which you said you couldn't do! (Well, it's a crappy option 2, and you *should* use a dynamic `$_GET['callback']` approach to get the function name, but it is still JSON-P).

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is in the JSONP data, when you send a request the JSON response would send a response as

```
callbackFunctionName(jsonData)
```

You do not have anything as such so is the issue you need to format the code as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'your cross domain file',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        crossDomain: 'true',
        jsonpCallback: 'MyCallback',
        async: true,
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
                console.log('error');
        }
    });

    function MyCallback(data) {  
    }

});
```

Now in the response the data needs to be formatted as

```
$data['response'] = 2;
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json_data =  json_encode($data);
echo "MyCallback" . '(' . $json_data . ');';
```

You can now check your console and see the data is coming through

You can check more on this here http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: See the comments on other answers. The OP has stated they can't send a JSON-P response.

Answer (score -1):

change your ajax to this code:

**Solution**

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: cross-domain-url,
                    data:{ param1:'123', param2:'123' },
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    success:function (data) {

                                alert('success');
                  },
                 error:function(){
                       alert('error');
                  }
             });
```

Hope it will work....

Comment: remove the  if (data[0].ResultCode) part and check again...please

Comment: I'm getting the same response.. Please understand. it is a cross domain issue. Is JSON suitable for it?

Comment: The data format doesn't matter. The access control headers I mentioned in my answer do.