# how to get facebook page feed in json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i was trying to get the facebook feeds in json using the jquery....

this is the script i am trying to achive the data

```
    $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=237173582992285&format=JSON',
        type: 'get',            
        dataType: "jsonp",          
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data successfully came ");
        }, error: function (data) {
            alert("fail to get the data");                
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/5Qqgh/2/)

**i have trace in mozila firefox.in console data is returning in json format...**

data is not  binding in success  method..
**data is binding in error method..**

please check this above snapshot attached here

[image]

Comment: After some testing and fiddling with the browser console ("Syntax error" in page.php?), I suspect the JSONP data format might be wrong, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456236/1781026

Comment: i can find the syntax error.. so how can i achive this feeds ? if i replace the /* dataType: "jsonp" */ to /* dataType: "json" */ ....no data is returning in this....give me solution to re-solve this issue..

Answer (score 1):

That URL doesn't allow for JSONP type requests because it doesn't wrap the JSON in a callback. You can however proxy the request through Googles feeds API, which can do cross-origin-resource loading.

```
<script>
  function jsapi_loaded(){
    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(
        "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=237173582992285"
      );
      feed.setNumEntries(10);
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=jsapi_loaded" async></script>
```