# I am getting this error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement firefox shows the error

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank

```
$("#get-results").submit(function (event) {
    console.log("Submitting new analysis...");
    event.preventDefault();
    //$("#question-submit").prop("disabled", true);
    var question = $('#question').val();
    var url1 = "https://@gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/solr/example_collection/fcselect?ranker_id=868fedx13-rank-702&q=does it support encryption &wt=json&fl=id,title,body";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url1,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'callback',
    });
    // JSONP Callback
    function callback(response) {
        //var glacier = JSON.parse(response);
        alert("Response from cross origin: " + response);
    }

});
```

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":70},"response":{"numFound":109,"start":
|_________________^
    is the response

Comment: where is the authentication ?

Comment: I did not paste it here... But it's there in my code.. The credentials... When I type url in Chrome I see a Json

Answer (score 0):

the response is a JSON but you are using dataType="jsonp" - jsonp is not json. `Change dataType: 'jsonp' to dataType: 'json'`

you should check here for more information:
[AJAX call and clean JSON but Syntax Error: missing ; before statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement)

Comment: thanks crescendo.. But I'm doing cross domain request.. It's necessary to use JSONP otherwise it shows error of another domain.. What should I do

Comment: in that link there is a reference to do a cross domain request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy